# Are there Monero developers who also contribute to the development of Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin

I wonder, if there are people who are experts both in Bitcoin and Monero.

Edit: To be more precise – I wonder if there are people who have any commits merged in both Monero and Bitcoin repositories.

Comment: Unless the term expert is defined (by merged GitHub commits or some measurable metric), this question cannot be answered. Please edit the question to make it clear what information you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no contributors of my knowledge in both Bitcoin and Monero.

However Monero has adopted many ideas from Bitcoin which have never been implemented there mostly due to politics around (hard) forks. Confidential Transactions (CT) have been extended and adopted by Monero as RingCT and also the initial idea of Stealth Addresses has been adopted from a proposal to the Bitcoin protocol. Even currently (once again) discussed Schnorr signatures are being in Monero since the first Cryptonote reference implementation.

In general you can say most of Monero's developers are very aware of methods used in Bitcoin but are not contributing to it directly (as of my knowledge). Still Bitcoin or any other open source project can adopt anything from Monero's codebase since it's fully open source.